# Why is it not loading in Pokemon go

Tags: pokemon-go

When I catch a higher level Pokemon it normally takes a few poke balls but at least half of the time I get this where it won't catch or escape and it just sits there and load what should I do

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me somewhat often. As devastating as it may be, I usually just close out the app and restart it. If it froze after the Pokeball settled I'll usually still have the Pokemon in my roster.